# Tuning SQL 2005 database using SQL 2008 tools?

Tags: sql-server, query-tuning

I have an assignment to tune a poorly performing query running on a SQL 2005 database. I have SQL 2008 management tools installed on my workstation. Can I use some of the new query tuning tools in 2008 like the data collector and system data collection sets to help analyze and tune this guy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe so.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677248.aspx

You can see the only versions listed are 2008, R2 and Denali.

Comment: From what I remember, those tools would help you get a picture of the server and find poorly performing queries. Maybe I'm wrong.  Thankfully SQL 2005 has dynamic management views which should help you quite a bit when tunign.